# Nodejs Mongoose guardar resultado de una consulta a una variable

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

tengo un problema a la hora de hacer una petición a una base de datos MongoDB en NodeJS utilizando Mongoose.

Lo que busco es hacer la petición a la base de datos (mongodb) y guardar el resultado en una variable. He probado lo siguiente:

```
let a = Comment.find({idArticle:n._id.valueOf()});
console.log(a);
```

y me devuelve un objeto enorme, pero si hago lo siguiente:

```
Comment.find({idArticle:n._id.valueOf()},(err,r)=>{console.log(r.length);});
```

veo que en consola funciona pero claro no se guarda en una variable, por lo tanto probé con lo siguiente:

```
let a = Comment.find({idArticle:n._id.valueOf()},(err,r)=>{ return r.length;});
console.log(a);
```

pero nada, seguía devolviéndome un objeto enorme, os dejo el código entero

```
Article.find({},"_id title author").exec((err, article) => {
  let template = [];
  article.forEach(n =>  { 
    let a = Comment.find({idArticle:n._id.valueOf()},(err,r)=>{ return r.length;});
    var d = new Date(n.date);
    template.push({
      title: n.title,
      author: n.author,
      date: `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth()}/${d.getFullYear()}`,
      id: n._id,
      comments: a
    });
  });
  role= getRole(req);
  res.render("adminArticulos",{
    session: role.user,
    json: template
  });
});
```

También probé de hacer lo siguiente:

```
 Comment.find({idArticle:n._id.valueOf()},(err,r)=>{
   var d = new Date(n.date);
   template.push({
     title: n.title,
     author: n.author,
     date: `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth()}/${d.getFullYear()}`,
     id: n._id,
     comments: r.length
   });
 });
```

pero cuando hacía el render

```
 res.render("adminArticulos",{
    session: role.user,
    json: template
  });
```

la variable template pasa vacía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es por asincronismo.

En la línea `let a = Comment.find({idArticle:n._id.valueOf()},(err,r)=>{ return r.length;});` piensas que es sincrono y no lo es, ya que la consultas a la base de datos de MongoDb son asíncronas, por lo que te devolverá una promesa sin resolver (ese famoso objeto enorme que comentas en tu consulta).

Como solución, te muestro varias soluciones, una con tu código, otra usando `async/await` y la ultima usando el método `aggregate`, asi podrás ver varias soluciones alternativas que pueden ayudarte a pensar el mejor camino para tu plataforma.

- Solución con tu código:

```
Article.find({}, '_id title author').exec((err, article) => {
    let template = [];
    article.forEach((n, index) => {
      Comment.find({ idArticle: n._id.valueOf() }, (err, r) => { // No haria falta el valueOf() si en el Schema de mongoose lo has definido como ObjectId
        const d = new Date(n.date);
        template.push({
          title: n.title,
          author: n.author,
          date: `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth()}/${d.getFullYear()}`,
          id: n._id,
          comments: r.length
        });

        if (index === article.length - 1) { // Cuando es el ultimo Articulo enviamos la respuesta
          const role = getRole(req);
          res.render('adminArticulos', {
            session: role.user,
            json: template
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

- Solución utilizando `async/await`:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => { // Añadimos la anotación de async para indicar que esta función es asíncrona
  const articles = await Article.find({}, '_id title author'); // A cada petición asíncrona añadimos await para que espere a que se resuelva la promesa para continuar con el hilo de ejecución.

  let template = articles.map(async (n) => {
    const comments = await Comment.countDocuments({ idArticle: n._id }); // Utilizon el meted countDocuments que nos devuelve el numero de resultados obtenidos.

    const d = new Date(n.date);

    return {
      title: n.title,
      author: n.author,
      date: `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth()}/${d.getFullYear()}`,
      id: n._id,
      comments: comments
    };
  });

  const role = getRole(req);

  res.render('adminArticulos', {
    session: role.user,
    json: template
  });
};
```

- Solución utilizando el método `aggregate` con las etapas para realizar la consulta de MongoDB:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const template = await Article.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: { // Etapa para realizar un join con la colección Comments
        from: 'comments', // Nombre de la colección
        localField: '_id', // El nombre del campo al cual emparejar con la otra colección
        foreignField: 'idArticle', // El nombre del campo de la colección a emparejar
        as: 'comments' // Nombre del campo que quieres que se devuelvan los resultados
      }
    },
    {
      $project: { // Etapa para procesar la devolución de los campos de cada documento
        _id: 0,
        id: '$id',
        title: 1,
        author: 1,
        date: { $dateToString: { date: '$date', format: '%d-%m-%Y', } }, // Si la fecha esta almacenada en formato Date
        // date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: '$date', format: '%d-%m-%Y' } }, Si la fecha esta almacenada en formato String
        comments: { $size: '$comments' }
      }
    }
  ]);

  const role = getRole(req);

  res.render('adminArticulos', {
    session: role.user,
    json: template
  });
};
```

Te dejo documentacion sobre [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) de MongoDB

Cualquier consulta, no dudes en preguntar para poder ayudarte.

Espero que este código te sea de ayuda.

Un saludo

Comment: Que buena la primera con el if (hay un mini fallo en el if, por si lo quieres cambiar, sería: article.length-1), creo que no se me abría ocurrido a mi, muchísimas gracias. Al final utilizare tu segunda opción, me parece muchísimo más limpia, y la última no la entiendo muy bien porque estoy aprendiendo, pero en un futuro volveré ;), muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección. Me alegra que te haya ayudado. un saludo